# Processing missing fields using SnakeYaml

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization, yaml, snakeyaml

Suppose I have a simple class that consists of two fields, getters and setters. I want to serialize and deserialize objects of this class sometimes.

```
public class Foo {
    private String a;
    private int b;

    public void setA(String a) {
        System.out.println("a setter called");
        this.a = Objects.requireNonNull(a, "Required non null field.");
    }

    public void setB(int b) {
        System.out.println("b setter called");
        this.b = b;
    }

    public String getA() {
        return a;
    }

    public int getB() {
        return b;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Representer representer = new Representer();
        representer.getPropertyUtils().setSkipMissingProperties(false);
        Yaml yaml = new Yaml(new Constructor(), representer);
        String doc = "b: 10";
        Foo testBean = yaml.loadAs(doc, Foo.class);
    }
}
```

I want the code in main method to throw some exception because field `a` is missing in `doc`. Unfortunately, it doesn't work so by default.

Can I configure SnakeYaml somehow to do that?

Comment: I'd also like to know if SnakeYaml can do this on its own... judging by the only answer so far, it's not possible without another library.

Answer (score 1):

Using a builder pattern is probably the best approach. Putting this all together, it ended-up being easier to do this with Jackson (not sure if it is / isn't doable with SnakeYaml by itself) and Immutables (https://immutables.github.io/) for the builder.

Note that you could write the builder yourself, and you could do validation in the `build()` method of the builder, but Immutables makes it all a bit easier.

First, your model class:

```
@Value.Immutable
@JsonDeserialize(builder = ImmutableFoo.Builder.class)
public interface Foo {
    String getA();
    int getB();
}
```

Note that by default `getA()` cannot return null (you could annotate it with `@Nullable` or make it an `Optional<String>` if you wanted to change that behavior). After running your annotation processor, you'll have an `ImmutableFoo` class with a builder with the desired semantics.

Then switch your de-serialization to use Jackson (which apparently uses SnakeYaml under the hood so shouldn't be super different):

```
new ObjectMapper(new YAMLFactory()).readValue("b: 10", Foo.class);
```

This will now throw a `JsonMappingException` whose cause is in the builder:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot build Foo, some of required attributes are not set [a]

If you want to avoid Immutables, you could do this kind of validation in your own builder.

Comment: Couple years late, but this helped me out. Thanks for the very clear and thoughtful explanation!